# live times in default receiver

Tags: javascript, google-cast

I have a chromecast sender application that is using the default receiver.

I am passing a live MPEG-DASH stream and all is working.

I have one concern the time that is displayed in the seek bar is incorrect it looks like a malformation of an epoch timestamp.

**example**

*416797:35:52*

is there anything I can do to make this timestamp work?

I am currently getting an epoch timestamp back as *currentTime* from the *remotePlayer*

I have bound the *RemotePlayerController* like the following

```
this._remotePlayer = new cast.framework.RemotePlayer();
this._remoteController = new cast.framework.RemotePlayerController(this._remotePlayer);
```

Answer (score 2):

This is because the `duration` for `live` is `infinity`. I had the same problem, I had to manually calculate progress to show it correctly, although you can't use it to seek to a position for live contents.

If you bind with `RemotePlayerController` it should handle this for you, this would basically disable seek bar and show you default `--` `--` start and end time.

Comment: I have bound to the RemotePlayerController (I have edited to the above to demonstrate)I think I'm missing how you calculate the progress with the default receiver

Comment: for `live` you can't depend on binding, you need need to create your custom progress bar. You have your `duration` in seconds, `currentTime` you will get from media status, this should be in seconds. Assuming your progress is ranged `0 - 1` progress will be `currentTime/duration`. You need to update your progress everytime you get an event from media status

Comment: are you using a custom receiver?

Comment: yah, is `416797:35:52` the `currentTime` value you get for default receiver?

Comment: yes I think that's what it comes up with from the epoch time, translated into HH:MM:SS, this is only a problem with a live stream.

Comment: seems like `currentTime` is [deprecated](https://developers.google.com/cast/docs/reference/chrome/chrome.cast.media.Media#currentTime), could you try with `getEstimatedTime` to check what you get?